# Tried using JavaFX & FXML but the program didn't work due to InvocationTargetExceptions and NullExceptions

Tags: java, exception, javafx, fxml

I am trying to learn JavaFX in eclipse, and I have installed it correctly. Since I do not want to code much layout since it is time consuming, I figured out that there is a way to model the GUI and that is FXML. However, when I tried to code my FXML, it has resulted in an error. For reference pictures:

[image: This is the directory]
[image: This is the layout]
I have these files:
**Main**

```java
package application;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        String fxmlDocPath = "/fxmltest/src/main.fxml";
        FileInputStream fxmlStream = new FileInputStream(fxmlDocPath);
        AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load(fxmlStream);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Example");
        stage.show();
        
    }
    
}
```

**FXML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="239.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
      <Text fx:id="title" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="34.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Scene Builder Sample" wrappingWidth="574.13671875">
         <font>
            <Font name="Corbel" size="27.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Text fx:id="nameDesc" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="54.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Enter your name below:" wrappingWidth="574.13671875" />
      <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="496.0" promptText="Enter your name!" />
      <Button fx:id="enter" layoutX="530.0" layoutY="61.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Enter" />
      <Text fx:id="expecDesc" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="119.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Enter your expectations below:" wrappingWidth="574.13671875" />
      <TextField fx:id="expecField" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="129.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="496.0" promptText="Enter your name!" />
      <Text fx:id="resultsfield" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="174.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Here are the results." wrappingWidth="574.13671875" />
      <Text fx:id="nameLabel" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="191.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name:" wrappingWidth="42.98307228088379" />
      <Text fx:id="expecLabel" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="215.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Results:" wrappingWidth="54.0" />
      <Text fx:id="nameShow" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="191.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text=" " wrappingWidth="474.9830722808838" />
      <Text fx:id="expecShow" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="215.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text=" " wrappingWidth="474.9830722808838" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the error code was:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \fxmltest\src\main.fxml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:22)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I am running this in Eclipse 2020-09 and I have followed the javafx installation from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC4XB6JAaoU.
How can I render this fxml then?

Comment: Start [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the main.fxml file and get the relative path. copy it an paste it into the following code..

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/relative_path_to/main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: tried it but it didn't work

Comment: a "relative-path" preceded by a slash is-a ... absolute path ;)

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: please use the directory convention used in maven.